# Change background color of active button

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 buttons. I want to change the background-color of only active button. I have written a j Query which is like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(value);
    if (value == "menu") {
        $(this).removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }

});
```

```css
.current {
    background - color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu" type="button" class="btn buttn">All</button>
<button class="menu" type="button" class="btn buttn">Tag1</button>
```

When i am clicking the button css property is not applying. Can anybody tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: why are you using two class attribute on the same element??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistake in css:

It should be like:  `background-color: blue;` instead of  `background - color: blue;`. Remove space from `background - color`

And include [JQuery plugins](https://jquery.com/) before your JQuery code.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9x51wsh/)**

And if you want color for only active class change JQuery like following:

Instead of `$(this).removeClass("current");` use `$('.menu').removeClass("current");` for remove class.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(value);
    if (value == "menu") {
        $('.menu').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }

});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9x51wsh/1/)**

Comment: @GauravTiwari So, it is working now. Have you add Jquery plugins?

Comment: @GauravTiwari What issue you are getting?  Have you check updated fiddle?

Comment: @GauravTiwari What happens when you click on button then?

Comment: Its not changing the background-color.

Comment: @GauravTiwari and it is adding current class?

Comment: When i click on the button i am only getting an alert message "menu".

Comment: @GauravTiwari Can you show me you css again? After change

Comment: no its not adding the current class, but when i replace  $('.menu') with  $(this) then its adding the current class.

Comment: .current {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

Comment: @GauravTiwari Can you show your new updated code by editing your question Or in  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hey its working now i have put the CSS property in the html file. Thanx for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('class');
  alert(value);
  if (value == "menu") {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
  }

});
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu" type="button" class="btn buttn">All</button>
<button class="menu" type="button" class="btn buttn">Tag1</button>
```

If there are only two of the buttons you can try using `.siblings()` to select the button you will remove the class from

Comment: I have tried your solution but its not working. Its not adding the current class.

Comment: how can you say it is not adding when the button is changing appearance can you check again @GauravTiwari

Comment: your code is working here fine but when i copy the same code and replace it with my code then its not working. I don't know why?

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?are you adding the buttons dynamically? @GauravTiwari

Comment: no i am not getting any error nor i am adding buttons dynamically. Its a simple static buttons.

Comment: @GauravTiwari it hard to tell what is wrong with you code if you cant create the same scenario in snippet.. your updated code is having error in adding `background-color`. fix it then replicate your code in that snippet

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var value = $(this).attr('class');
   alert(value);
   if (value == "menu") {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
   }

});
```

and change the css background - color to  background-color

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
 $('button').click(function() {       
        if ($(this).attr('class').toLowerCase()== "menu") {
  $('.menu').removeClass("current");   
            $(this).addClass("current");
        }
    });
```

CSS Class

```
.current {
  background-color: blue; // also change here
  color: white;
}
```